# Did I really lose all data? ubuntu will not boot after volume group ubuntu-vg not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a Dell R-730xd with 6 16TB drives managed by PERC controller in a raid 5 array.  I have been adding disks as I can and the 6th one came online today.  So naturally I wanted to increase the file system size as I have done before.  But today I screwed up somewhere.

I had Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS running no problem before I did the following to try and expand the volume.  No encryption.  Now all I can get to is the initramfs shell as I get the error

> Gave up waiting for root device, ubuntu--vg-root doesn't exist

I did run the gparted live and it shows unknown for sda3.  It does see it but its just unknown. Hopefully someone can help me through this as I dont want to loose 48tbs of data.  I booted to ubuntu live and thats where I am at as of now.

Below is the full output file from my ssh session where it all went wrong?..  the link below should allow you to download the text file.

[output.txt](https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aj6nxrUfTwWh2BbysPSV4GLdMrIC?e=PRKzRL)

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Would of been a lot easier if I did not reboot..

Comment: Saw you writing a GPT. Is that usual when hou add a disk?

Comment: Typically not with GPT, think that was one of my mistakes this round.  Normally its lvextend then resize2fs.  Update - I was able to use testdisk from a live cd boot and restored where I can now see the files under the volume.  I now need to restore the ubuntu-vg.  I found this https://www.golinuxcloud.com/recover-lvm2-partition-restore-vg-pv-metadata/ but I am not sure I understand it all.  I also dont want to loose my data so I am being very cautious.  Can any one explain more on the restore of a vg or what else I might need to do to restore this system?  Thanks in advance.